# Linking C++ static libraries with QtCreator

Tags: linker, qt-creator, static-libraries

I am using QtCreator 4.2.1 with MinGW4.9.2 32 bit compiler (Win 8.1 platform).
My **pgi** project only has a **main.cpp** which uses objects and functions belonging to my **PhygenicLib** static library. This static library in turn relies on functions and classes and constants defined in the **Mathlib2** static library along with the **eigen3** template library  (template-based, only headers, no .cpp!) found on the web. 
Here is the **PhygenicLib.pro** which compiles nicely into the **libPhygenicLib.a** file (debug mode):

```
QT       -= gui
TARGET = PhygenicLib
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Qt-apps/Mathlib2 d:/Qt-apps/eigen3
SOURCES += phygenic.cpp \ cinemeca_pg.cpp \ mecagen.cpp \ 
    rc_perf_pg.cpp \ xploit_pg.cpp \ utilities.cpp \
    Analex.cpp \ Anasyntax.cpp 
HEADERS += phygenic.h \ cinemeca_pg.h \ mecagen.h \ rc_perf_pg.h \
    xploit_pg.h \ utilities.h \ Analex.h \ Anasyntax.h
unix { target.path = /usr/lib
INSTALLS += target }
```

Here is the **pgi.pro** (debug mode):

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = pgi
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
LIBS += d:/Qt-apps/build-Mathlib2-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/libMathlib2.a \
    d:/Qt-apps/build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/libPhygenicLib.a
INCLUDEPATH += d:/Qt-apps/PhygenicLib \
           d:/Qt-apps/Mathlib2 \
           d:/Qt-apps/eigen3
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS +=
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
```

Note that Mathlib2 is compiled in release mode not debug mode, but that should not be a problem (?). Now, here is my **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Anasyntax.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**)
{
    ofstream fdmp("test"+extFichier[DMP]);
    try { // bloc try
        fdmp<<"--- test généraux interpréteur ---"<<endl ;
         Anasyntax asynt ;
        asynt.interprete(fdmp);
    } catch (std::exception const& err) {  
        fdmp << err.what()<< endl<<" - Erreur fatale." << endl ;
        cerr << err.what()<< endl<<"- Erreur fatale." << endl ;
    }
    cout<<'\a' ; 
    fdmp << "--- FIN DE L'EXECUTION --- "<< std::endl;
    fdmp.close() ;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

**#include Anasyntax.h** is pulling all the headers from the various libraries wherever required (root of the include tree, so to say).
Now when I try to compile and link the project, I get the following diagnostic (sorry the language, QtCreator installed in French):

```
14:48:12: Exécution des étapes pour le projet pgi...
14:48:12: Débute : "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" clean
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt-apps/build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
del debug\main.o
Impossible de trouver D:\Qt-apps\build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\main.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt-apps/build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release clean
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt-apps/build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
del release\main.o
Impossible de trouver D:\Qt-apps\build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\release\main.o
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Qt-apps/build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
14:48:13: Le processus "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" s'est terminé normalement.
14:48:13: Configuration inchangée, étape qmake sautée.
14:48:13: Débute : "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt-apps/build-pgi-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -std=c++0x -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\pgi -I. -Id:\Qt-apps\PhygenicLib -Id:\Qt-apps\Mathlib2 -Id:\Qt-apps\eigen3 -IC:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\include -IC:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\include\QtCore -Idebug -IC:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\mkspecs\win32-g++  -o debug\main.o ..\pgi\main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\pgi.exe debug/main.o  d:/Qt-apps/build-Mathlib2-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/libMathlib2.a d:/Qt-apps/build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/libPhygenicLib.a -LC:/Qt/5.5/mingw492_32/lib -lQt5Cored 
d:/Qt-apps/build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/libPhygenicLib.a(mecagen.o): In function `ZN10Solide_dyn4calcEv':
D:\Qt-apps\build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../PhygenicLib/mecagen.cpp:220: undefined reference to `rotation_WM(V3)'
D:\Qt-apps\build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/../PhygenicLib/mecagen.cpp:221: undefined reference to `Mat_transp_3x3(Mat3x3)'
and so on, and so on...
```

It looks like g++ is trying to link **mecagen.cpp** (which is already compiled as part of libPhygenicLib.a) and not finding references to symbols which are part of **Mathlib2** library (includepath= d:/Qt-apps/Mathlib2, LIB= d:/.../release/libMathlib2.a). 
I found a walk-around solution: just inserting in the **main.cpp** a reference to any Mathlib2 object or function, such as function **coupure** hereafter, enables to build and run the project executable without any warning/error:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    ofstream fdmp("test"+extFichier[DMP]);
    coupure(0.,0.,0.) ; // any object or function from Mathlib2 works as well!
    try { // etc...
```

So the problem is overcome but it drives me nuts not to understand why it won't work without inserting a useless code line... I have to say I was too lazy to ever learn about g++, make, qmake and makeFile sort of things; just pushing QtCreator buttons is so easy and comfortable...

Answer (score 0):

I read again some posts with somewhat similar issues and found one comment regarding the order of declaring static libraries which may be critical in some cases.
And indeed, if I declared the LIBS in my **pgi.pro** in the reverse order, as follows:

```
LIBS += d:/Qt-apps/build-PhygenicLib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug/libPhygenicLib.a \
    d:/Qt-apps/build-Mathlib2-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/libMathlib2.a
```

the project then compiles and links fine without any extraneous reference to a Mathlib2 object or function in the **main.cpp**. I got the lesson and will now take care of declaring LIBS in the appropriate order...